# How do I set custom trigger for comparing old value with new one and executing function depending on result?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need an actual working gs code for this but I cant seem to find the correct function for this so I scraped an explainable version of this, it works like an onEdit function

```
function(value, modifier) {
 if (value < modifier) = setBackground("red");
}



function(value, modifier) {
 if (value > modifier) = setBackground("blue");
}
```

what I want:

- change cell color and cell highlight color to red if new input value is greater than previous one
- change cell color and cell highlight color to blue if new input value is less than previous one

Answer (score 2):

`onEdit(e)` has in the event object with properties `e.value` and `e.oldValue` so if you enter a new value in the cell you could use that to compare to the value that was previously in the cell.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if( e.value > e.oldValue ) {
    e.range.setBackground("red");
  }
  else if( e.value < e.oldValue ) {
    e.range.setBackground("blue");
  }
  else {
    // value didn't change
    e.range.setBackground(null);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)